# SSTable folder naming convention

Tags: hash, cassandra, directory, naming

I just noticed that my newly created sstable folder has a combination of numbers and letters attached. For my table "tweets" it looks like:

```
/var/lib/cassandra/data/twitter/tweets-a6da23906d8211e8a057ffb9a095df5c
```

on the disk. Does anybody know what this attached hash is?

Thanks! 
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder name consists of table name, and table ID that is generated anew every time when the table is created - this is done to prevent race condition when table created, dropped, created, etc.