# Cassandra internal structure

Tags: cassandra

I have a table threshold when i see internal I saw data like this

- thresholds-013f8630812a11e885581d42d0727985

  thresholds-0ab8f8e0713511e8849d85e38fe317db

  thresholds-18c19550b2a411e7845cd18bd49bef86

  trojan_horse-18b0f380b2a411e7845cd18bd49bef86

Now I want to know why Cassandra create so many data files for the table thresholds?
and also kindly tell how to know which one is having my data to backup?

Comment: What Cassandra version do you use? The names listed above are subfolders within another folder (which is keyspace name)? Did you delete the table and recreated it? Also, did you check this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html)?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand that why these directories are there but the question is for multiple directories? For the backup why one I keep? say for thresholds ?I am using  Cassandra 3.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSTable folder naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114269/sstable-folder-naming-convention)

Comment: Combining with the info provided by Alex Ott I think you should check the time when those folder were created and check the logs to see what has happened. All folders have files inside?